# How to get python unittest to show log messages only on failed tests

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-logging

#### Issue

I've been trying to use the [unittest --buffer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#cmdoption-unittest-b) flag to suppress logs for successful tests and show them for failing tests. But it seems to show the log output regardless. Is this a quirk of the logging module? How can I get the log output only on failing tests? Is there a special config on the logger that is required? Other questions and answers I've found have taken a brute force approach to disable all logging during tests.

#### Sample Code

```py
import logging
import unittest
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger('abc')

logging.basicConfig(
    format = '%(asctime)s %(module)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
    level = logging.INFO,
    stream = sys.stdout)


class TestABC(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_abc_pass(self):
        logger.info('log abc in pass')
        print('print abc in pass')
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_abc_fail(self):
        logger.info('log abc in fail')
        print('print abc in fail')
        self.assertTrue(False)
```

###### Test Output

```
$ python -m unittest --buffer
2021-09-15 17:38:48,462 test INFO: log abc in fail
F
Stdout:
print abc in fail
2021-09-15 17:38:48,463 test INFO: log abc in pass
.
======================================================================
FAIL: test_abc_fail (test.TestABC)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../test.py", line 22, in test_abc_fail
    self.assertTrue(False)
AssertionError: False is not true

Stdout:
print abc in fail

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 3.401s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

So the buffer does successfully suppress the output from the `print` statement in the passing test. But it doesn't suppress the log output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### A Solution for the Sample Code

Just before the test runs we need to update the stream on the log handler to point to the buffer unittest has set up for capturing the test output.

```py
import logging
import unittest
import sys

logger = logging.getLogger('abc')

logging.basicConfig(
    format = '%(asctime)s %(module)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
    level = logging.INFO,
    stream = sys.stdout)


class LoggerRedirector:

    # Keep a reference to the real streams so we can revert
    _real_stdout = sys.stdout
    _real_stderr = sys.stderr

    @staticmethod
    def all_loggers():
        loggers = [logging.getLogger()]
        loggers += [logging.getLogger(name) for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict]
        return loggers

    @classmethod
    def redirect_loggers(cls, fake_stdout=None, fake_stderr=None):
        if ((not fake_stdout or fake_stdout is cls._real_stdout)
             and (not fake_stderr or fake_stderr is cls._real_stderr)):
            return
        for logger in cls.all_loggers():
            for handler in logger.handlers:
                if hasattr(handler, 'stream'):
                    if handler.stream is cls._real_stdout:
                        handler.setStream(fake_stdout)
                    if handler.stream is cls._real_stderr:
                        handler.setStream(fake_stderr)

    @classmethod
    def reset_loggers(cls, fake_stdout=None, fake_stderr=None):
        if ((not fake_stdout or fake_stdout is cls._real_stdout)
             and (not fake_stderr or fake_stderr is cls._real_stderr)):
            return
        for logger in cls.all_loggers():
            for handler in logger.handlers:
                if hasattr(handler, 'stream'):
                    if handler.stream is fake_stdout:
                        handler.setStream(cls._real_stdout)
                    if handler.stream is fake_stderr:
                        handler.setStream(cls._real_stderr)


class TestABC(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # unittest has reassigned sys.stdout and sys.stderr by this point
        LoggerRedirector.redirect_loggers(fake_stdout=sys.stdout, fake_stderr=sys.stderr)

    def tearDown(self):
        LoggerRedirector.reset_loggers(fake_stdout=sys.stdout, fake_stderr=sys.stderr)
        # unittest will revert sys.stdout and sys.stderr after this

    def test_abc_pass(self):
        logger.info('log abc in pass')
        print('print abc in pass')
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_abc_fail(self):
        logger.info('log abc in fail')
        print('print abc in fail')
        self.assertTrue(False)
```

#### The How and Why

The issue is a side effect from both how `unittest` is capturing the `stdout` and `stderr` for the test and how `logging` is usually set up. Usually `logging` is set up very early in the program execution and this means the log handlers will store a reference to `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` in their instances ([code link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9443ce4eedbcaffb3262e7ede1dd100678e85506/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1058)). However, just before the test runs, `unittest` creates a `io.StringIO()` buffer for both streams and reassigns `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` to the new buffers ([code link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9443ce4eedbcaffb3262e7ede1dd100678e85506/Lib/unittest/result.py#L64)).

So right before the test runs, in order to get `unittest` to capture the log output, we need to tell the log handlers to point their streams to the buffer that `unittest` has set up. After the test has finished, the streams are reverted back to normal. However, `unittest` creates a new buffer for each test so we need to update the log handlers both before and after each test.

Since the log handlers are pointed to the buffer that `unittest` set up, if there was a failed test, then all the logs for that test will be displayed when using the `--buffer` option.

The `LoggerRedirector` class in the solution above just offers convenience methods to reassign all the handlers that might be pointed to `sys.stdout` or `sys.stderr` to the new buffer that `unittest` has set up and then an easy way to revert them. Since by the time `setUp()` runs, `unittest` has already reassigned `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` we are using these to reference the new buffer `unittest` has set up.